# In Swift, how to customize the more menu on a tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to change the back ground and size of the cells but on the more menu but am not sure how to do so.  Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

I want to add a ui image as a backgrounds as well as add a ui image as a background to each cell so it will look like this:

[image]

I saw an old post about this on Stack Overflow but it was 7 years old.  Does anyone know how to change the more menu in Swift?

Comment: just add image to the cell in `cellForRowAt...` method

Comment: Yeah the more menu can be tricky, check out this link it might give some support http://initwithstyle.net/2014/02/making-more-of-the-more-view/

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard 
1) add a uiImageView to the ViewControll or TableViewControll that you are using. set Constraint UImageView to SuperView as equal width,equal length,central horizontally and central vertically.

set outlet to access.

2)  set tableview background to clear colour in attribute property

3)in tableview cell add a UIImageView and set the same equal width, length ,central horizontal and central vertical to contentView.
cell.background colour should be clear .

based on tab you should change the background image in tableview cell imageView in cellforIndexMethod.

you can change the background image of mainBackground in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear based on the tab